# 10 days in South Korea using an Australian Passport, whilst on a Chinese visa

Tags: visas, china, south-korea, australian-citizens

Do I need a visa for a 10 day holiday to South Korea? I have an Australian passport living in China on a z visa.

Answer (score 3):

No. Australians are offered 3 months without a visa in South Korea. You being on a Chinese visa should hold no weight on your trip to South Korea.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Australian_citizens#cite_note-118